# How can I download the data from this site?

Tags: python, selenium, request

I'm trying to build a script using selenium to click on the Download button of stock data from this site.
https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/busca-avancada

The script is running like this:

1 - It opens the site

2 - It clicks on the "Buscar" button to list the stocks
then I was trying to use a request to get the data, but when I'm trying to search for the link I can't find one.

I'd like to get the data to transform to a database using pandas.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime
from random import randint
import pandas as pd

chromedriver_path="C:\\Users\\PICHAU\\Desktop\\projeto_dashboard\\chromedriver.exe" # Change this to your own chromedriver path!
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
sleep(2)
webdriver.get('https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/busca-avancada')
sleep(3)



button_login = webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('#main-2 > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div > button.find.waves-effect.waves-light.btn.btn-large.btn-main.fw-700.fs-3.pl-2.pr-2.pl-sm-3.pr-sm-3.tooltipped')
button_login.click()
sleep(3)

#import urlib.request 

#f = urlib.request.urlopen('http:')
#data = f.read()
#with open("data.zip", 'w') as code:
#    code.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)                                 

driver.get("https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/busca-avancada")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.btn-close"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#main-2 > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div > button.find.waves-effect.waves-light.btn.btn-large.btn-main.fw-700.fs-3.pl-2.pr-2.pl-sm-3.pr-sm-3.tooltipped"))).click()
```

To click the Buscar element. First remove the element popping up and then clicking it by css_selector.

[image]
Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hi, Arundeep. Thank you for the answer. I know that there's a pop up that sometimes prevents clicking the "Buscar" button. but the main problem is downloading the file that is generated after clicking it.